# Why is the ggplot not generating any plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I wanted to plot a animated plot using gganimate , here is the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
library(gganimate)

rain<-read.csv("csvrainfall.csv")
temp<- read.csv("temp.csv")

mean_temp<-temp$Temp

> #computing mean annual rain
rain$mean_ann_rain<- apply(rain[,-1], 1, function(x) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE))

> #combining the two datasets
combined_rain_temp<- cbind(rain, mean_temp)

> #transforming the data from wide to long form 
long_combined<- melt(combined_rain_temp, id.vars = c("Time", "mean_ann_rain", "mean_temp"), variable.name = "Region", value.name = "Rainfall")

ggplot(long_combined, aes(x=mean_ann_rain, y= mean_temp))+ geom_point()+ labs(title = 'Year:{frame_time}',
                                                                                   x="Mean annual rainfall",y="Mean annual temperature")+
  transition_time(Time)+ ease_aes('linear')+shadow_wake(.03)
```

The code is not generating any error, it also generated the .png files needed to do the job, but just plot is not getting displayed. Sample dataset:

```
temp <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Time, ~Temp,
  1951L, 24.22,
  1952L, 24.34,
  1953L, 24.57,
  1954L, 24.13,
  1955L, 23.97,
  1956L, 23.96,
  1957L, 23.97,
  1958L, 24.62,
  1959L,  24.3,
  1960L, 24.29
)

rain <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Time, ~Andaman.and.Nicobar.Islands, ~Assam.and.Meghalaya, ~Naga.Mani.Mizo.Tripura,
  1951L,                       3275.1,               2613.8,                  2609.3,
  1952L,                       3079.9,               2851.3,                  2810.9,
  1953L,                       2721.9,               2559.9,                  2661.6,
  1954L,                         3449,               2859.1,                  2905.1,
  1955L,                       3349.6,               2761.2,                    2865,
  1956L,                         3080,               2802.9,                  3022.7,
  1957L,                       2507.2,               2257.2,                  2303.9,
  1958L,                       2807.4,               2626.4,                  1968.6,
  1959L,                       3343.3,               2535.8,                  2327.6,
  1960L,                         3025,               2342.2,                  1799.9
)
```

Comment: When I run your code there is a plot in the viewer tab in RStudio?

Comment: Your code also works for me. Animations are displayed in the Viewer tab (not the Plots tab). Does running `gganimate::anim_save()` save the animation in a way you would expect?